# Running Ansible playbook using AWS Systems Manager (skipping: no hosts matched)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I'm trying to run an ansible playbook from Github repo using AWS Systems Manager. Basically, I'm running the Ansible playbook from the AWS Systems Manager Console --> Run command --> AWS-ApplyAnsiblePlaybooks --> Specify the Github repo location --> Choose the target instances --> Run.

The actual Ansible command running behind the scene is in the following format:

```
ansible-playbook -i localhost -c local -e <extra variables> <verbose> <playbookfile>
```

My repo has a hosts (ini format) file as shown below:

```
[dev]
server.example.com
```

And my playbook looks like below:

```
---
- name: test run
  hosts: dev
  become: true
```

When I run the playbook, I get the errors below:

```
PLAY [test run] ********************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched
```

```
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: dev
```

It works fine if I change 'hosts: all' in the playbook instead of the group name 'dev'. But, I just only want to run against a group.

Any idea why it is not picking up the hosts? Can someone help me to resolve this issue, please?

Comment: You didn't include how you are actually running ansible, and because you mentioned SSM your inventory file is missing a huge number of variables that the [aws_ssm connection plugin needs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/5/collections/community/aws/aws_ssm_connection.html#parameters). In other words, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72547240/edit) and provide more detail about the actual problem you're having. Good luck

Comment: Thanks. I have added more details to the original question.

Comment: _My repo has a hosts (ini format)_ per default, Ansible only consider _/etc/ansible/hosts_ as an inventory file. You will need to provide the path to your inventory to _"AWS-ApplyAnsiblePlaybooks"_.

Comment: [_The default location for inventory is a file called `/etc/ansible/hosts`. You can specify a different inventory file at the command line using the `-i <path>` option._](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#how-to-build-your-inventory)

Comment: Another way, if that is accepted by this tool, is to have an _ansible.cfg_. in the root of your repository and there, define the path to your inventory. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#default-host-list

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried adding the ansible.cfg file and defined the path to inventory. Unfortunately, still get the same error.